# Python MySQL connection argument error

Tags: python, mysql, arguments, database-connection, mysql-python

I am trying to write a simple program to connect MySQL and perform some operations

```
host = '10.0.106.40'
user = 'ddddd'
port = 3306
passwd = 'DDDDDD'
db = 'bbbbbbb'

''' Creates a MySQL connection and returns the cursor '''
def create_connection():
    connection = mysql.connect(host, user, passwd, db, port)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor


''' Close the connection '''
def close_connection(cursor, connection):
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

The above functions are my skeletons. Now, when I try to do this

```
for user in users:
    connection, cursor = create_connection()
    ...
    close_connection(cursor, connection)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: connect() argument 2 must be string, not long
```

However, when I do this

```
connection, cursor = create_connection()

for user in users:    
    ...

close_connection(cursor, connection)
```

The code runs perfectly fine! I'm not sure but why should that be? I really want to run the earlier version of the code as the latter one is too slow for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `user` being passed to `create_connection()` is from the line

```
for user in users:
```

That is why it works outside the loop, because then it is accessing the correct `user`, namely the one with a String datatype.

An alternative would be to use a `while` loop instead or change the line to something like:

```
for u in users:
```

Or else you should do what warwaruk suggests.

Answer (score 0):

`users` is a list of integers?

That's why it's bad to deal with globals. Better pass some parameters to `create_connection` instead of taking values from globals:

```
def create_connection(host, user, passwd, db, port):
    connection = mysql.connect(host, user, passwd, db, port)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor
```

Comment: Yes, users is a list of integers. I have tried passing parameters to the create_connection method instead of global values. So definitely the problem doesn't lie in there.

Comment: `users` should be a list of strings, as `mysql.connect(host, user, passwd, db, port)` expects second parameter - user name